# Cisco Unity Connection guest, ESXi host, IP phones, vlan, subnet, ip addresses, qos

Tags: cisco, vlan, qos, voip

I have setup:

- `VLAN 1` and `subnet 192.168.1.0/24` for data
- `VLAN 100` and `subnet 192.168.100.0/24` for voice
- IP phones get their IP via DHCP on the `subnet 192.168.100.0/24`
- all other IP devices get their IP on `subnet 192.168.1.0/24`

I am using "Cisco Unity Connection" for auto-attendant and voicemail.

**Question 1:**
In which subnet "Cisco Unity Connection" server should be put?

`subnet 192.168.100.0/24` or `subnet 192.168.1.0/24`?

**Question 2:**
The "Cisco Unity Connection" server VM is running inside a Vmware ESXi host.
In which subnet Vmware ESXi host should be put?

`subnet 192.168.100.0/24` or `subnet 192.168.1.0/24`?

I am asking these questions with QoS in mind, with voice traffic prioritization perspective.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'll suggest using a third vlan for infrastructure.

Depending on what your are using for routing between vlan, this may help you to protect your infrastructure (access list, firewalling), enable QoS on both "user" subnets (voice and data) aso.